# How to insert multiple rows into a SQL table similar to a 'For Each' loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-analysis

I have a table in SQL with a structure like:

| ID_COL | VALUE_1 | VALUE_2 | VALUE_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| B | 2 | 8 | 6 |
| B | 4 | 7 | 6 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| C | 7 | 9 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For each distinct `ID_COL` value (A, B, C, etc.) I need to add a row. Every row being inserted will have the same values for the `VALUE_X` columns. For example, I'll add a row with values `A, 1, 2, 3`, `B, 1, 2, 3`, etc.

Is there any way to do this programmatically in SQL without having to generate a bunch of separate insert statements? I'm not super familiar with SQL, but in another language like Python I would do a for-each loop on the distinct `ID_COL` values.

If it makes a difference, this is in SQL Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Use an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` or a `INSERT INTO... SELECT ... FROM`.

Comment: Do you want to insert only one row for each `ID_COL` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to resort to looping for this kind of thing. Your question is lacking any real details about your table or what you really want to accomplish. So assuming you want the value 1, 2, 3 along with each distinct value of ID_COL it would be something like this.

```
insert YourTable
select distinct ID_COL
    , 1
    , 2
    , 3
from YourTable
```